# cannot get Locality using Geocoder and GPS in android

Tags: android, geocoding, google-geocoder

Hi i am trying to get City,Locality, Latitude , Longitude using geoCoder location and gps

It is working on maximum devices but not working on galaxy s4, sony , or samsung tablet

Be more specific it is not working on xperia z1 (android 4.1.1., model C1505)

Here is code snippet for geocoder

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
     List<Address> addresses;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, longi, 1);
        Log.e("geocoder size", addresses.get(0).getLocality()+"");


        //setCityName(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
        //setStateName(addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
        //setCountryName(addresses.get(0).getCountryName());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```